# Dispersion of cavity photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

I read a paper called "strong coupling phenomena in microcavity structure" in that with regard to photons in a microcavity

> For small $k$, the dispersion is parabolic, and so it can be described by a cavity photon effective mass $M = hnc/cLc$. This mass is very small, typically ∼$10−5me$ [10]. Such dispersions can be measured directly in angle tuning experiments (as discussed in section 6): moving away from normal incidence in a reﬂectivity measurement introduces an in-plane component to the photon wavevector [3]. In-plane wavenumbers up to $k \approx 107 \,\text{m}^{−1}$ can be probed in this way

Do the lines corresponding to the dispersion for photons in the graphs below demonstrate the difference between photons with different $k$ vectors (ignoring all the excitons and stuff).

[image]

Comment: What is defined by the vertical axis in the graph on the left?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do. The horizontal axis of the graph gives the information of the k component parallel to the propagation plane (it is connected to the angle through a sine). So you can see the photon dispersion as (in units hbar=1):

Ephot(k)= omega_o+k^2/2m, where k is the in-plane mometum of the photons.

Comment: Hi Daniel, we do have MathJax enabled on this site so that you can write LaTeX-style equations. Search "notation" in [help] for more details.